# Error when creating model of custom gym environment using stable baselines 3 algorithms

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I coded Tetris using pygame and now I am trying to create an agent that is able to play it using stable baseline 3. Therefore I created a gym environment for the game, where the observation_space is a 2D Array of the field containing a 0 on every empty field and a 1 on every field that is occupied by a figure:

```
from src.figure import Direction
from tetris import Tetris, GameStatus
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, MultiBinary
import pygame

class TetrisEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self, field_size) -> None:
        self.height, self.width = field_size
        self.observation_space = MultiBinary([field_size[0], field_size[1]])
        self.action_space = Discrete(6)
        self.game = Tetris(self.width, self.height)
        self.score = 0
        self.episodes = 10000
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def step(self, action):
        self.episodes -= 1
        match action:
            case 0:
                pass
            case 1:
                self.game.move(Direction.LEFT)
            case 2:
                self.game.move(Direction.RIGHT)
            case 3:
                self.game.drop_figure()
            case 4:
                self.game.rotate(Direction.LEFT)
            case 5:
                self.game.rotate(Direction.RIGHT)
    
        status = self.game.move(Direction.DOWN)

        reward = self.game.score - self.score + (1 if status != GameStatus.GAME_OVER else 0)
        self.score = self.game.score
        done = self.game.state == GameStatus.GAME_OVER or self.episodes <= 0
        return self.game.field, reward, done, {}

    def render(self):
        self.game.draw()
        self.clock.tick(4)

    def reset(self):
        self.game = Tetris(self.width, self.height)
        self.score = 0
        self.episodes = 10000
        return self.game.field
```

When I now try to create a model I get the following error:

```
from stable_baselines3 import A2C
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

env = TetrisEnv((20, 10))
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
model = A2C('CnnPolicy', env, verbose=1)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    model = A2C('CnnPolicy', env, verbose=1)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/a2c/a2c.py", line 115, in __init__
    self._setup_model()
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py", line 111, in _setup_model
    self.rollout_buffer = buffer_cls(
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/buffers.py", line 342, in __init__
    super(RolloutBuffer, self).__init__(buffer_size, observation_space, action_space, device, n_envs=n_envs)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/buffers.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.obs_shape = get_obs_shape(observation_space)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/preprocessing.py", line 153, in get_obs_shape
    return (int(observation_space.n),)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you run a check on your environment ... from stable_baselines.common.env_checker import check_env

Comment: @Bhupen if I run it, it does not generate any output (I checked on the environment before converting to a DummyVecEnv)